# Is there any resolution difference?

Tags: c++, c, numeric, numerical-methods

Given `float A` and `float B`, is there a difference between:

```
float C = A * B;
```

And:

```
float D = (float) ( (double)A * (double) B);
```

Comment: Neither will compile, so no, there is no difference.

Comment: did you really mean capital F `Float` in your 2nd example?

Comment: Why don't you try and see? (ignore the case and no semi colon, making it look like pseudo code) It is too much examining each of the steps in compiler or printing them,

Comment: The short answer is yes it can make a difference, but the full answer of 'how much' depends wholly on what you're doing with the result, and what kind of numbers you're working with.

Comment: Did you mean `float C = (float) A * (float) B;`?

Comment: modify the question, yes, I mean float

Comment: what are `A` and `B`?  If they are `double` then there certainly could be a difference.

Comment: @fayyazkl “Why don't you try and see?” For every pair of floats `A` and `B`? Will that not take a long while?

Comment: @PascalCuoq  Oh no, i meant trying one example and check intermediate results. You would know if it is implicitly promoted to doubles or not, which would be the only factor creating any difference.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to interpret your question.  I believe that you're really asking if, given `float`s `x` and `y`,

```
float z = x * y;
```

is numerically equivalent to:

```
float z = (double)x * (double)y;
```

This question cannot be answered in full generality, as C and C++ require very little of the types `float` and `double`.  However, if one assumes that `float` and `double` are IEEE-754 binary32 and binary64, respectively, then the answer is yes; both expressions are computed with only a single rounding, which is required by IEEE-754 to be correctly rounded, so the results are the same.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you intend to do is to compute the expression in `double` precision and then assign to a single precision (`float`) variable.

The answer is no , "there is no difference", the results will not be different. The reason is that variables `A` & `B` are defined as `float` therefore upgrading them to `double` during calculations cannot improve the accuracy. If you want to improve precision, define `A` & `B` as `double`. A better test would be to try a near singular expression.

Comment: Your reasoning is wrong. If the types were `double` and `long double` instead of `float` and `double`, there would be no loss of information when converting from `double` to `long double`, but there would be loss of information when converting the `long double` result from `long double` to `double`. The end result would be “double-rounded” (rounded twice), and less accurate than the result of `double d = d1 * d2;`. The difference would seldom be visible, but it would exist, and perhaps paradoxically, the `double` computation would be better than the `long double` one.

Comment: @PascalCuoq The argument was not about loss of precision it was about whether there is a difference or not between the two results. For example, let the numbers be `float x = 3.141592, y = 1.0`, now typecasting it to `double` during calculations `float z = (float)((double)x * (double)y)`, will temporarily upgrade 3.141592 to the closest possible `double` mostly by padding zeros at the end. Therefore there will be no change in result.

Comment: If the reasoning in this answer was correct then it would apply to `double` and `long double`. The conversion from `double` to `long double` also extends from 64 to 80 bits by adding zeroes and preserves the value. However, 0x1.39d6f77f65b98p+62*0x1.4b94b1e48fe65p+58=0x1.967f3c5ea32a9p+120 but (double)((long double) 0x1.39d6f77f65b98p+62 * 0x1.4b94b1e48fe65p+58))=0x1.967f3c5ea32aap+120. This shows that the reasoning in this answer is incorrect.

Comment: The property that `(float)((double)floatA * (double)floatB)` is equal to `floatA * floatB`  holds for reasons that are more complex than those stated in this answer, and these reasons do not apply to `double` and `long double`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I think you are missing the point here that the extra accuracy that you are talking about, is error! When we define a variable value say `x = 2.0` it is not stored as 2.0 exactly. It may be stored as say 2.0000001 or 1.999999. When we increase the precision `float` to `double` (or `double` to `long double`) by typecasting, the same thing happens extra zeroes are padded, but since exact representation of a number in binary is not possible it will be the best possible representation of the number. Therefore the extra information is error due to conversion, not accuracy.

Comment: Actually 2.0 is stored exactly. Please read the question again. The question is whether `floatA * floatB` is equal to `(float)((double)floatA * (double)floatB)`, your answer is yes, this answer is right, but not for the reasons you give. The reasons you give would apply to `double` and `long double`, for which the property is false.